# ASP.NET on Samsung Internet browser

Tags: asp.net, samsung-mobile

Certain functionality within ASP.NET (4.5) isn't working on Samsung's Internet browser. For example, LoginStatus, GridView paging, MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback.

As this is the default browser on Samsung mobiles and our mobile site is built with ASP.NET this is a problem. All the above functionality works fine when we use Chrome on the same mobile devices.

Is this a known problem and are there any workarounds?

Jon

Comment: I work at Samsung Internet but I've not used ASP.NET... Might it be possible to share example(s) / test case(s) that we could use to start debugging?

Comment: A link button works like this: <asp:LinkButton ID="hlForward" runat="server" OnClick="btnForward_Click">Checkout</asp:LinkButton> - then there is a page behind code file in C# which contains a method like this: protected void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { C# login goes here } - but the event is never fired. The problem must be deeper - due to the actual framework itself I guess - which I wouldn't understand. Thanks, Jon